# megacli all the Disks in a VD(RAID 6) are missing

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, megaraid, megacli

I have a server with LSI MegaRAID SAS 9286CV-8e. After an incident, this server which 4 VDs(RAID 6) only 2 are back. When I scan for foreign configurations it says 3 foreign configurations found. But none can be imported.

All the disks which belong to the Failed VDs, showing as "Foreign".

In the webbios, the VDs are showing "Not Importable"

When I preview a foreign config it shows disks missing.

I didn't clear any Foreign configuration yet.

Comment: What incident was happened?

Comment: it is a Raid card failure and replaced the raid card

Comment: Model of new raid card is the same as old one?

Comment: No it is different

Comment: Try to update RAID firmware. Before it unplug all  disks. Did you have a mix of SAS and SATA disks in one array?

Comment: Did the same. Updated the card with the latest firmware.disconnected the JBOD, before doing the update. We don't have a mix of SAS and SATA drives. All of them as SATA.

Comment: Immediately after the replacement, all the 4 VDs were not shown and all the disks were shown as "Foreign". After the Firmware update, 2 VDs out of 4, are recognised. For other 2 VDs, all the disks are showing foreign still.

Comment: Do rescue from backup.